Getting a WebDriverException while connecting to chrome driver with Selenium
I am trying to scrape a website using Selenium with chrome WebDriver.I am trying to connect to the chrome webdriver, But I am getting a WebDriverException error.
Here's my code:
website = 'https://www.adamchoi.co.uk/overs/detailed'
chrome_driver_path = r'C:\Users\Aved Debbarma\Downloads\chrome-win64\chrome-win64\chrome.exe'
 
# Create a Service object with the path to ChromeDriver
service = Service(chrome_driver_path)
 
 
 
# Optionally, configure options for Chrome
options = Options()
# options.add_argument('--headless=new')  # Uncomment this line if you want to run Chrome in headless mode
options.headless = True
 
 
# Create a WebDriver instance with the specified Service and Options
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)

driver.get(website)
all_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//label[@analytics-event="All matches"]').click()  # //label[@analytics-event="All matches"] <THIS IS THE X PATH REMEMBER
all_button.click()
  
matches = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('tr')

Here's the error I am getting
WebDriverException                        Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[16], line 16
     12 options.headless = True
     15 # Create a WebDriver instance with the specified Service and Options
---> 16 driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
     22 driver.get(website)
     23 all_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//label[@analytics-event="All matches"]').click()  # //label[@analytics-event="All matches"] <THIS IS THE X PATH REMEMBER
 

 
File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py:109, in Service.start(self)
    107 count += 1
    108 if count == 70:
--> 109     raise WebDriverException(f"Can not connect to the Service {self._path}")
 
WebDriverException: Message: Can not connect to the Service C:\Users\Aved Debbarma\Downloads\chrome-win64\chrome-win64\chrome.exe


Any help is appreciated

is "chrome.exe" in your path correct there? Usually it'd be "chromedriver.exe".

Yes, that's for sure the problem
